# Create dynamic association according to db values

Tags: associations, ruby-on-rails-4

In a Rails4 app I'd like to create dynamic associations.

I have the following models:

```
class Pilot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end

class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pilot
end
```

Cars have an attribute color and I'd like to create as many associations as available colors

For instance if I have 1 red car, 2 blue cars and 1 green car, I'd like to have in my pilot model

```
has_many :red_cars
has_many :blue_cars
has_many :green_cars
```

The point is that I don't know the colors that will be picked up.

Is it possible to implement it?

Thanks.

UPDATE

I guess I can probably do something like

```
#untested. Written just now
Car.all.map(&:color).uniq.each do |color|
  has_many "#{color}_cars".to_sym, -> { where(color: '#{color}') }, class_name: 'Car'
end
```

If nothing better is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add conditions to your `has_many` associations (make sure they are the first argument).

```
class Pilot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  has_many :red_cars, -> { where(color: 'red') }, class_name: 'Car'
end
```

You can make this even more nicely organized with [named scopes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope).

```
class Pilot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  has_many :red_cars, -> { red }, class_name: 'Car'
end

class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pilot
  scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }
end
```

When you go with the named scopes, you can always do `@pilot.cars.red` to find all red cars belongs to a pilot, and if this is convenient enough for you, you might not need a custom `has_many :red_cars` association at all.

**Update**

If you don't know the color you want to retrieve beforehand, you can pass dynamic conditions into a named scope.

```
class Pilot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end

class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pilot
  scope :with_color, ->(color) { where(color: color) }
end
```

In your controller, you can then select `@pilot.cars.with_color('red')` and `@pilot.cars.with_color(params[:color])`. I'd not want to create hardcoded `has_many :red_cars` associations in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however my issue is a bit more complicated. I don't know which color cars have since they can be selected when a new record is created.

Comment: I need to group cars by color. So I cannot pass a color to the controller but I need to get all the cars divided by color. I'd like to have a single association (or virtual attribute) for each color.

Comment: How are your colors defined and do new ones get added at runtime? If not, you have all the tools you need with `named scopes` and `group_by`. If you really want to have associations, why not loop over an array of colors and build the associations dynamically in this loop?

Comment: Yes colors can be added at runtime.
So, the solution is a loop like in my update. Thx

Comment: @macsig I think the loop will be evaluated only one, when the process starts. So it will only pick up on colors that are present on booting or rebooting. You could shorten and speed up `Car.all.map(&:color).uniq` to `Car.pluck(:color).uniq` (this won't load all car records into memory).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to treat the colors as `enums` Rails4+ will create scopes for the enums based on the types:

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html